# Viewing the existing MySiteHostLocation for the SPProfileServiceApplication

Tags: 2010, powershell, user-profile-service

I've found plenty of example of how to set the `My Site` host location for the User Profile service application.

> On the Start menu, click **All Programs**. 
>   Click **Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products**. 
>   Click **SharePoint 2010 Management Shell**. 
>   At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following command:
>   `Set-SPProfileServiceApplication [-Name <UserProfileServiceApplicationName>] -MySiteHostLocation <URL>`

Instead I want to check what location was originally set up for the User Profile service application. Is there `Get-SPProfileServiceApplicaiton` command that would give me these details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Get-SPServiceApplication` and the `-Identity` or `-Name` parameters to get the User Profile Service Application. The returned object will have the My Site Host Location.

Comment: I returned the object and called $obj.mysitehostlocation this returned the info I needed.